# Show required custom validator error message in to associated textbox

Tags: asp.net

I have a text box control that I'm wishing to apply custom field validation to. The data I'm validating in the text box is used as a primary key in the database I've set up. I need custom validation controls that allow me to check for duplicates before the data is submitted.

I would like the user to be prompted to enter different input if the validation returns that the data exists.

Comment: Are you saying you want an error message to show if the input text violates a primary key constraint?

Comment: yes i want error message appear when user key in same data that i set as primary key.

Comment: try doing it first without a custom validator. Just use another textbo for the error message. So --> User inputs text. They submit. It posts back. You take the text and make a call to the database to see if it is invalid. If it is invalid, store a new message in the error-textbox.

Comment: You really need to post some code examples. We can't help with specifics if you don't give us anything to go off.

Comment: thank all because helping i'm done solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

you better add OnTextChange property to textbox and perform the primary key validation in that function.